# convert string date to timestamp in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

I have a Mutablelist with 2 metadata from the file var/log/apt/history.log, the metadata are Start-Date and Commandline.

If I print my list I get

```
[, Start-Date: 2021-04-03  16:52:18, Commandline: apt-get install unrar, Start-Date: 2021-04-04  15:21:36, Commandline: apt install telegram-desktop, Start-Date: 2021-04-07  19:38:19, Commandline: apt install dia]
```

How to select the Start-Date(string) and to convert to timestamp in kotlin?

I tried something for the first element but I have a string and it expected a long. How to separe "Start-Date" from that date?

```
val tStamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(metaList.elementAt(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a Date object from the string date (*metaList[1]*):

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val date = format.parse(metaList[1])
```

Then you can convert the date object to a timestamp:

```
val tStamp = Timestamp(date.time)
```